# Cuda combination algorithm error : CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I am trying to implement Combination algorithm described in this article https://www.developertyrone.com/blog/generating-the-mth-lexicographical-element-of-a-mathematical-combination/  on CUDA.

it works for C(100,4)

```
     n=100
     k=4
```

but when I try C(200,4) I got error message **CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED**.

```
    n=200
    k=4
```

I am almost sure that there is no overflow for calculating  combination of n=200 but I couldnt figure out the reason.

I debugged the code and there were no overflow.
One interesting point is, the code sometimes run for C(150,4) and sometimes fails.

I forced all integers as int64.
I tried to remark each line one by one to find the exact position causing the error.
When it seems that the problem is with this 2 lines in function largestV

```
    while choose(v, b) > x:
        v -= 1
```

When I remarked this 2 lines, it does not crash.

Full code is below:

```
import numba
from numba import cuda
import math
import numpy as np
from pdb import set_trace


@cuda.jit(device=True)
def choose(n, k):
    if n < k:
        return 0
    if n == k:
        return 1

    delta = imax = 0
    if k < n-k:
        delta = n-k
        imax = k
    else:
        delta = k
        imax = n-k

    ans = numba.int64(delta + 1)

    for i in range(2, imax+1):
        ans = numba.int64((ans * (delta + i)) / i)

    return ans


@cuda.jit(device=True)
def largestV(a, b, x):

    v = numba.int64(a-1)
    while choose(v, b) > x:
        v -= 1

    return v


@cuda.jit
def cuda_calculateMth(n, k, d_result):
    pos = cuda.grid(1)     # pylint: disable=not-callable
    if pos >= len(d_result):
        return

    m = numba.int64(pos)
    a = numba.int64(n)
    b = numba.int64(k)
    x = numba.int64((choose(a, b) - 1) - m)

    for i in range(k):
        d_result[pos][i] = largestV(a, b, x)

        x = x - choose(d_result[pos][i], b)
        a = d_result[pos][i]
        b -= 1

    for i in range(k):
        d_result[m][i] = (n-1) - d_result[m][i]




if __name__ == "__main__":

    n = 200
    k = 4
    totalcount = int((n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)) / (4 * 3 * 2))
    result = np.zeros((totalcount, 4), dtype="uint")
    temp = np.zeros(10, dtype="uint")

    d_result = cuda.to_device(result)
    d_temp = cuda.to_device(temp)

    threadsperblock = 128
    blockspergrid = (totalcount +
                     (threadsperblock - 1)) // threadsperblock

    cuda_calculateMth[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](  
        n, k, d_result)
    result = d_result.copy_to_host()
    print(result[-30:])
```

Comment: I think you are hitting a kernel timeout.  Would be helpful to know what kind of GPU you are running on as well as the OS.   For `n` of 200 running on my (small) GPU the kernel requires about 6 seconds.  Also note that the required GPU memory grows rapidly as you increase `n`, i.e. by the 4th power of `n`.  However for n=200 I believe it is still only consuming about 2GB of GPU memory.

Comment: I dont think that it is a timeout issue because I checked it with nvprof and execution times are less than 1 sec.

Comment: win10 geforce 750m

Comment: It is a timeout issue. The code in your question runs fine for me, but on a much faster GPU than your laptop it takes 3.5 seconds, of which 2 seconds is the kernel execution time

Comment: I dont think that it is a timeout issue. I checked it with nvprof and it takes les then 1 sec.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it again and it looks like timeout issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  talonmies, it is timeout issue.
I set TDR Timeout to 30 and now it works.